# Displaying value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I want to display the value from the searchbar into Search results for " ".

This is what I got so far, why doesn't this work?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" value="" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<p>
Search results for  "<span id="result"></span>"
</p>

<button onclick="myname();"> Button </button>

<script>
function myname () {
 document.getElementById("autocomplete").value = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML; 
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6):

The data you want to copy goes on the *right* hand side of the equal sign, the place you want to put it goes on the *left*.

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because your assignment is the wrong way around.

```
document.getElementById("autocomplete").value = document.getElementById("result").innerHTML
```

Should be:

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="autocomplete" value="" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
<p>
Search results for  "<span id="result"></span>"
</p>

<button onclick="myname();"> Button </button>

<script>
function myname () {
 document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = document.getElementById("autocomplete").value; 
}
</script>
```